# How can I hide the Object and Enum methods from code completion?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just uploaded Eclipse to 23-09 (4.29.0) version and it seems that I can't hide anymore the Object and Enum default methods from code completion.

Up to now, I got it working by using the Type Filters preferences, adding the java.lang.Object and java.lang.Enum* filter names. It was working brilliantly, only showing the new methods I was adding in each class and enum.

But with the last update this doesn't seem to work. I have included a couple of photos to have a visualization aspect as well.

Can you enlighten me?

[image: Code Completion]

[image: Type Filters settings]

Comment: Huh, that's brilliant. This removes `Object` itself from autocomplete as well but I'm not going to forget that exists and it's not hard to type. It works for me right now, I'm on 4.27 though.

Comment: Might be a regression that warrants opening an Issue.

Comment: Check the log. Was that a clean installation or an upgrade on existing one? Try starting with `-clean` switch or with a new workspace.

Comment: I tested it in both. I upgraded my previous installation and, at the time I realized the issue, I made a clean new one redownloading the IDE. Neither of them worked as expected